# Jira process just goes away

Tags: jira

i am trying the self hosted JIRA 
it only seems to stay up for 30-45 minutes and then the process just goes away. The strange thing is there are no errors in catalina.out
the last error in the catalina.out is

> 02-Mar-2017 12:13:26.989 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5]
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.filterFormParameters
>   A servlet request, to the URI
>   http://localhost:8080/rest/activity-stream/1.0/preferences?_=1488474809006,
>   contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has
>   been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request
>   parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as
>   expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means
>   will not work as expected.

if i grep fatal or errors i do not find anything 
Any suggestions on what i can do to debug this?
I did see lots of threads on running out of memory, but i could not find any errors that mentioned out of mem and i am the only one using it

the two log files i have been looking in are

> /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/log/atlassian-jira.log
>
> /home/atlassian/jira/logs/catalina.out

thanks for any help

Comment: Well best way to investigate it is via atlassian-jira.log and don't look after the error only. Check what happened prior to the stop. Also, are you running it in a VM? What's your JAVA version? Are you seeing any JVM crash log?

Comment: On top of that, if you are seeing outOfmemory error or warning, just increase your memory a bit and check how it goes after that :-)